# ASP.NET MVC session randomly does not return value with key

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-cookies, session-state

Storing company info in the session with key. Sometimes session does not return value with valid key. I have suspicion that firewall can block or change session id during request. Issue happens randomly and after refreshing page, everything work as expecting. Any experience you faced?

Thanks

Randomly occur and after refreshing page, all is fine

Comment: A firewall either blocks traffic completely or not. It definitely does not alter data in any way.

Comment: I suggest you add a bunch of javascript that echoes the value to isolate where the issue is. Some code wouldn't hurt also.